# Importing data from SQL Server DB to another using SSMS Import/Export wizard

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

When I'm importing data from SQL Server 2008 DB to another using SSMS 2008, I get errors during the importation because it tries to insert data in a "read only" fields, or cuz some conflicts of relationships between tables' keys.

I'm wondering, how could I close the eyes of the SSMS until he finish the transformation :D

Thanks, Regards

Comment: I've resolved the error of the "read only" by editing "Enabling Identity Insertion", still the other problem, I'm wondering again, If I can re-order the insertion of the tables I can solve the problem, couldn't I?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you reorder your table data insert statements you should be able to resolve foreign key/relationship issues. You could use an ER diagram (e.g. in SSMS Database Diagrams, select all tables) to first insert the data for the tables other tables depend on/point to with foreign keys, and then work your way down the dependencies.

I wonder how you generated these scripts; I'd imagine that any tool worth it's salt would generate data insert scripts in the proper order.